# Best Hosting solution for Draughts/Checkers Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm developing a draughts/checkers app. Its main purpose is to allow people sign up and play against each other.

Its only a college project and initially the ability to handle lots of concurrent users is not of concern. My initial concern is to get it up and running for demonstration purposes.

I had a look at 'heroku'. You can sign up for free, and you get 1 dyno.
Would this be enough for me initially? Would I be able to manage source control and get the app up and running to allow 2 people play a game? Is it very straight forward for someone that is only ok at linux?

I may look at putting it out to be used by the public at a later stage.

Any other tips of advice for hosting solutions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku sounds ideal for you and incredibly easy to get started. I have about 25 apps on Heroku that all scale differently depending on App need with the largest app supporting tens of thousands of simultaneous connections running on 6 dynos. Most only need one. The quick start guide should have you up and running in 5 minutes if you have git already set up.

[Heroku's Quickstart Guide](http://docs.heroku.com/quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Heroku would be great for this kind of app.  You can support more than 2 people concurrently and not spend any money unless you need to (which you won't initially).